# JDBC connection with a database on the same machine

Tags: sql, r, networking, jdbc

Lets say i want to use the RJDBC package to connect with a database on the same machine as where the R script is going to be executed and from where the JDBC connection is going to be established. Is requesting and getting the data from the database faster than if the R script was on another machine than the database?

Since it is reaching the data through the same machine and therefore the same network i would think that it is faster.
Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of "transfer throught the network" performance, yes. It would be faster.

However, there are multiple factors to consider in the overall performance of a query. If the database is running on a fast machine, then the query may run faster. If the database runs in the same machine than your application, then both may compete for resources (memory, cpu, I/O) and that can negatively impact the query performance.

So, bottom line, is that depends.